# method that takes no argument, using for loop to add numbers to arraylist

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, methods

This method will fill the `ArrayList` with the numbers 1 through 10 while using a for loop that takes no argument. The method I'm trying to do this in is `create_pegboard` near the top. What should I fill in for the for loop to accomplish this?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PegBoardGame {

    public static ArrayList create_pegboard(){
        //for loop and add method to holes 1-10
        for(){

        }
    }

    public static void print_pegboard(ArrayList pegboard) {
        //print results from array 1-10 or final result
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(pegboard);
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    }

    public static Integer peg_hole(ArrayList pegboard){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //variable for user input
        int holetofillInt;
        int checkInt;
        //prompt for input
        System.out.println("Select a peghole 1-10 to fill");
        holetofillInt = in.nextInt();
        //if peg chosen by user is already 0 then print error message
        checkInt = pegboard[holetofillInt];
        if(  ){ 
            System.out.println("Peghole is already filled!");
        }
        else{
            //set selected hole to 0
            pegboard.set(holetofillInt,0);
            return holetofillInt;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create array list with peghole numbers
        ArrayList<Integer> pegboard = create_pegboard();
        //print the pegboard unchanged
        print_pegboard(pegboard);
        //construct array list up to 10
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            //see if they want to change and change what hole is peggged
             peg_hole(pegboard);
             //print changed peghole board
             print_pegboard(pegboard);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue do yu have?

Comment: I'm not sure where to start with the for loop without using arguments

Comment: Where would you start with the for loop if you did have arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method should create a new ArrayList of integers, then fill it with the numbers 1-10 using a for loop, and then return the newly filled list that you've created.

This does what you're looking for.

```
public static ArrayList create_pegboard(){
//for loop and add method to holes 1-10
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 1; i<=10; i++){
    list.add(i);
     }
return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no arguments being passed in make sure that the array has scope within the entire class and then just do it the same way you would outside of the method.

My suggestion would be to have the array passed in though.